# Input Autocomplete - hide items until a value is entered

Tags: javascript, html, list, listview

I'm just trying to figure out how to hide the list search items until at least 1 character is typed into the search bar instead of having all the listings shown before anything is typed. Thank you in advance for any help I've been trying to figure this out a few weeks now

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";

    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 94%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search " title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank" rel="external nofollow">test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://google.com/ "target="_blank" rel="external nofollow">test 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank" rel="external nofollow">test 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://google.com/ "target="_blank" rel="external nofollow">test 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank" rel="external nofollow">test 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank" rel="external nofollow">test 5.5</a></li>   
</ul>
```

Comment: your `onkeyup` will fail as soon I paste a string into your field. Instead, use `oninput`

Comment: Also your HTML double quotes are all messed up.

Answer (score 0):

- In **CSS** use `display: none;` for your LI elements - to hide them by default.
- In **JavaScript** set a LI item to *display* `"block"` only if

  1. input value has length
  2. it's (LI's) text *contains* input value

(A Pseudo-code would be: `display = inputValue && containsText ? "block" : "none"`)

- Hide all other *non-matching* LI elements

```js
const input = document.getElementById("myInput"); // Cache your elements!
const li = document.querySelectorAll("#myUL li");

const suggest = () => {
  const val = input.value.trim(),       // Trim the value. Don't fool sloppy users
        reg = new RegExp(val, "i");     // "i" = Case insensitive
  [...li].forEach(el => el.style.display = val && reg.test(el.textContent) ? "block" : "none");
};

input.addEventListener("input", suggest); // (Don't use inline JS in HTML)
```

```css
#myUL li {display: none;} /* HIDE BY DEFAULT */
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search " title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a>test 1</a></li>
  <li><a>test 2</a></li>
  <li><a>test 2.1</a></li>
  <li><a>test 3</a></li>
  <li><a>test 4</a></li>
  <li><a>test 5</a></li>
  <li><a>test 5.5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: **works :)** What browser are you using? Also, have you tried to enter some words into the input like `2` or `test` ? @DCR

Comment: using chrome, I enter text nothing happens in the snippet

Comment: @DCR what text? Try to enter the number `2` and enjoy the auto suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the best solution, but it can work.
Hope can help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=400, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 94%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>.</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search " title="Type in a name">


<ul id="myUL">

        <li><a href="http://google.com/"target="_blank" rel="external nofollow"">test 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com/"target="_blank" rel="external nofollow"">test 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com/"target="_blank" rel="external nofollow"">test 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com/"target="_blank" rel="external nofollow"">test 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com/"target="_blank" rel="external nofollow"">test 5</a></li>
        <li><a href=http://google.com/"target="_blank" rel="external nofollow"">test 5.5</a></li>

<script>
disapper();
function disapper(){
 var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
 for( var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
  ele[i].style.display = 'none';
 }
}
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (filter === '') {
         disapper();
         return;
        }
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this

Set the default style for `#myUL` in your css to be hidden like so

```
#myUL {
  display: none;  /* #myUL is hidden by default */
}
```

And then on your javascript file using jquery do

```
$("#myInput").keyup(function(){   // When a user releases a key from keyboard
  if ($("#myInput").val())   // If field not empty
    $("myUL").show();  // Show list
  else                       // If field is empty
    $("myUL").hide();  // Hide list
});
```

Don't forget to include jQuery file on your html file like so. IMPORTANT you must add jQuery first first before you include any javascript code, so you might want to add the at the very top or add it at the very bottom and include your script tags at the end

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```